# How to add subreports in main reports using java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating jasper pdf using java. I wan to add subreports dynamically to main report.

Main reported is created using below code :

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("/home/report1.jrxml");
    jasperDesign.setName("sampleDynamicJasperDesign");
    jasperDesign.setPageWidth(595);jasperDesign.setPageHeight(842);jasperDesign.setColumnWidth(595-40-40);jasperDesign.setColumnSpacing(0);
    jasperDesign.setLeftMargin(40);jasperDesign.setRightMargin(40);jasperDesign.setTopMargin(20);jasperDesign.setBottomMargin(20);

    JRDesignStyle normalStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
    normalStyle.setName("Noto Sans");normalStyle.setDefault(true); normalStyle.setFontName("Noto Sans");normalStyle.setFontSize(12);normalStyle.setPdfFontName("Helvetica");normalStyle.setPdfEncoding("Cp1252");normalStyle.setPdfEmbedded(false);jasperDesign.addStyle(normalStyle);
((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(createHeaderSubreport(parameters));
```

//create subreport

```
    private JRBand createHeaderSubreport(Map<String, Object> parameters) throws JRException {

    JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign(); 
    jasperDesign.setLanguage("java");
    jasperDesign.setPageWidth(595); jasperDesign.setPageHeight(842);jasperDesign.setColumnWidth(595-40-40);jasperDesign.setColumnSpacing(0);jasperDesign.setLeftMargin(40);jasperDesign.setRightMargin(40);jasperDesign.setTopMargin(20); jasperDesign.setBottomMargin(20);
    jasperDesign.setTitle(null);jasperDesign.setColumnHeader(null);

    JRDesignParameter designParameter = new JRDesignParameter(); designParameter.setName("LeftText");designParameter.setValueClass(String.class);
    jasperDesign.addParameter(designParameter);
    JRDesignStyle normalStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
    normalStyle.setName("Noto Sans");normalStyle.setDefault(true);normalStyle.setFontName("Noto Sans");normalStyle.setFontSize(12); normalStyle.setPdfFontName("Helvetica");normalStyle.setPdfEncoding("Cp1252"); normalStyle.setPdfEmbedded(false);jasperDesign.addStyle(normalStyle);

    JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(50);

    JRDesignStaticText designStaticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    designStaticText.setText("Header");
    designStaticText.setHeight(10);
    designStaticText.setWidth(100);
    designStaticText.setX(0);designStaticText.setY(0);
    band.addElement(designStaticText);

    JRDesignTextField jrDesignTextField = new JRDesignTextField();
    JRDesignExpression jrExpression = new JRDesignExpression();
    jrExpression.setText("$P{LeftText}");
    jrDesignTextField.setExpression(jrExpression);
    jrDesignTextField.setY(0);
    jrDesignTextField.setHeight(20);
    jrDesignTextField.setWidth((38*515)/100);
    jrDesignTextField.setMarkup("html");
    jrDesignTextField.setHorizontalTextAlign(HorizontalTextAlignEnum.LEFT);
    jrDesignTextField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
    band.addElement(jrDesignTextField);

    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    JRDesignSubreport jSubreport = new JRDesignSubreport(jasperDesign); 
    jSubreport.setUsingCache(false); 
    jSubreport.setRemoveLineWhenBlank(true); 
    jSubreport.setPrintRepeatedValues(false);
    jSubreport.setWidth(500);
    jSubreport.setHeight(80);
    jSubreport.setX(0);jSubreport.setY(0);

    JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText("new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)");
    jSubreport.setDataSourceExpression(expression);        
    jSubreport.setExpression(expression);

    JRDesignSubreportParameter designSubreportParameter = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();  designSubreportParameter.setName("REPORT_CONNECTION");    
    JRDesignExpression exp = new JRDesignExpression("$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}");  designSubreportParameter.setExpression(exp);
    jSubreport.addParameter(designSubreportParameter);


    designSubreportParameter = new JRDesignSubreportParameter();  designSubreportParameter.setName("LeftText"); 
  exp = new JRDesignExpression("$P{LeftText}");  designSubreportParameter.setExpression(exp);
  jSubreport.addParameter(designSubreportParameter);

    band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(80);
    band.addElement(jSubreport);
    return band;
}
```

Then after compling and filling main report, subreport is printing as blank.But individually subreport works.

Even I have tried by passing dataSourceExpression as **new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{notes})** still its printing blank.

I am not getting where I am wrong, Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile your design.

```
JasperReport subReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subJasperDesign);
```

Then add it as param to your main report.

```
parameters.put("SUB_TEMPLATE", subReport);
```

Get this param in jrxml template:

```
<parameter name="SUB_TEMPLATE" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
```

And finally jrxml usage example of this param:

```
<band height="15">
<subreport>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="15" />
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{SUB_DATASOURCE_NAME}]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUB_TEMPLATE}]]></subreportExpression>
/subreport>
</band>
```

Comment: How i can add subreport using java, i don't wont to do any configuration in jrxml because height and width of report element <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="802" height="15" /> will be decide at run time.

Comment: How to pass 'JasperReport subReport' as subreport expression using java?